# How to fetch unread messages of a particular user through rocketchat rest api

Tags: rocket.chat

I am working on rocket.chat integration. I need to fetch all unread messages of a particular user through rest api. Do anyone know any method that will do this task? Couldn't find any in the documentation as well.

Comment: I have also tried for this same thing but not got solution from REST API. So i have build my logic. Like when first time fetch the messages then store the last seen timestamp. When next time make request then pass that last seen timestamp under oldest param under REST API. So that way it will only return those messages which are after last seen timestamp.